# How to use option's localStorage in a Chrome Extension with manifest version 2?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, manifest

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Port error while changing chrome extension from manifest v1 to v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11913575/port-error-while-changing-chrome-extension-from-manifest-v1-to-v2)

Looking to make my first Chrome Extension, but I've ran into a pickle when I started to look at using the `option` page's `localStorage` with the `www.example.com/example.html`'s `localStorage`. I've looked around for how to pass messages back and forth between the two, with this page on [Message Passing](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html), but seems like I'd need to set up the eventListener, and use `SendRequest`s in `background.html` which isn't allowed in `manifest : 2`:

```
There were warnings when trying to install this extension:
'background_page' requires manifest version of 1 or lower.
```

edit: you need to make the changes to `manifest` [as seen here](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifestVersion.html), to use `bac

The [Message Passing](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html#connect) page talks about creating a Port, but it's unclear on where to put the listener. If I put the first half into the `content.js` script, then the other half into `options.js`, the listener it only active when the `options.html` is open.

So my question is: How do I pass settings I've chosen in `options.html`  to be usable in  my `contentscript.js` which manipulates the current webpage?

---

Here's my entire set up:

background.html

```
 <!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Background Page</title>
    <script src="jquery.min.js"/>
    <script src='background.js'/>

</script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

background.js

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.method == "getLocalStorage")
      sendResponse({data: localStorage[request.key]});
    else
      sendResponse({}); // snub them.
});
```

contentscript.js

```
chrome.extension.sendRequest({method: "getLocalStorage", key: "status"}, function(response) {
  console.log(response.data);
});
```

manifest.js

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "Image replacer",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "A script to replace all images in the browser with images from any given Imgur gallery",
    "browser_action": {
        "name": "Image replace BA",
        "icons": ["icon.png"],
        "default_icon": "icon.png"
    },

    "background": {
        "page": "background.html"
    },

    "permissions": ["storage"],

    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://www.imgur.com; object-src 'self'",

    "content_scripts": [{
        "js": ["jquery.min.js", "contentscript.js"],
        "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"]

    }],
    "options_page": "options.html"
}
```

Comment: [Background pages](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages.html) **do work** in manifest v2. You have to use the new syntax instead (eg `"background": {"scripts": ["background.js"]}`).

Comment: See [Port error while changing chrome extension from manifest v1 to v2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11913575/port-error-while-changing-chrome-extension-from-manifest-v1-to-v2). The answer to your question is phrased at the bottom of the accepted answer. Before it, additional relevant information is provided (common pitfalls).

Comment: @RobW Alright, I've gotten the manifest updated, the contentscript is now creating a request, and I've got a listener in `background.js`, but still getting an undefined response error

Comment: I'm not good at debugging invisible code ;) Can you edit your question to provide the relevant code? (the documentation for `onMessage` is partially incorrect by the way, have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11811554/chrome-extension-port-error-could-not-establish-connection-receiving-end-does/11811936#11811936). Does it solve your problem?).

Comment: @RobW Edited the code in, you answer looks like it'll work, I'll try it out.

Comment: You're not using any features of a HTML document. So, I suggest to use `"background": {"scripts": ["jquery.min.js", "background.js"] }` instead. If you still want to use `"background": {"page": "background.html"}`, then you must also use `<script src="..."></script>` - Self-closing script tags don't work.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, I just started getting familiar with HTML/JS last night. Don't I need `background.html` to place the listener there, in order to share the option settings?

Comment: You're not inserting *any* non-script HTML elements. Therefore, I advise to use a background script (`background.html` will be auto-generated and embed your scripts). The event listeners are bound to the chrome API objects, not to any specific DOM element, so..

Comment: @RobW Great, that solved the issue then. If you care to, please submit this solution as answer and I'll accept it!

Comment: If you edit the question to phrase your situation, I'll post a matching answer. See, your current Q&A cannot easily be found through Google, because your question's title and introduction doesn't match the actual problem and solution.

Comment: @RobW That's fair, as I misunderstood what was actually happening. I'll edit it. We're all friends here. I can see now too, that you properly recognized the question as a duplicate, though I didn't feel the same at the time.