# CHROME 21 Support for manifest version 1 is being phased out. Please upgrade to version 2

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am using Chrome 21. Everything is working fine but I am getting this warning message -
**"Support for manifest version 1 is being phased out. Please upgrade to version 2."**. If I am updating manifest version 2 my script.js is not working. I am getting wrong result for my plugin. How to solve this problem ? Could somebody please help me out..

**MANIFEST FILE:**

```
{
  "name": "Email_Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 1,
  "icons": {

    "16": "EOE(16x16).png",
    "48": "EOE(48x48).png",
    "128": "EOE(128x128).png"

  },
  "description": "Eyes On Emails New",

  "permissions": [
    "http://api.eyesonemails.com/","http://192.168.0.197/","http://www.sagaciousinfosystems.com/","tabs"
  ],

  "content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
    "css": ["style.css"],
    "js": ["jQuery 1.7.1.js","script.js"]
  }
  ],
  "background": {
    "page": "background.html"
  },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "Eyes on Emails",
        "default_icon": "EOE(48x48).png"

    },

   "web_accessible_resources": [
     "images/loader.gif",
     "images/email-wrong.png",
     "images/email-correct.png",
     "images/eye-icon.png"

  ],
  "options_page": "options.html"
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Port error while changing chrome extension from manifest v1 to v2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11913575/port-error-while-changing-chrome-extension-from-manifest-v1-to-v2)

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to **"Changes between version 1 and 2"** section of [this documentation page](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifestVersion.html). All necessary changes you'll have to make in your extension are described there.

Answer (score 0):

`"manifest_version"` should be assigned to 2, your mainfest.json should appear like that

```
 {
 "name": "Email_Extension",
 "version": "1.0",
 "manifest_version": 2,
  ...
}
```

check the [documentation](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifestVersion.html) for chrome extension upgrade.